# 'Find' sequences of size 3 in a dataframe column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a datetime dataset that contains a column where all 'days off' are identified as **1s** and the rest are **0s**. I am trying to create a new column that identifies extended periods off, say 3 days or more. I need to either select those sequences of **1s greater than 3 in a row (eg: 01110)** or **discard single (010) and doubles 1s (0110)**.

An example dataset follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'days_off': [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]})

df['extended_off'] = np.NaN
```

I've tried a convoluted for loop to look at all the conditions, it appears to be working except at the first two rows, which i cant iterate over with my solution (below)

Is there a better way???, since you really should avoid looping over a df.

```
for i in range(2, len(df)):     
    if ((df.loc[i-1, 'days_off'] == 0) and (df.loc[i+1, 'days_off'] == 0)): # single holiday (wednesday)
        df.loc[i, 'extended_off'] = 0
    elif ((df.loc[i-1, 'days_off'] == 0) and (df.loc[i+2, 'days_off'] == 0)): # normal weekend (no prior)
        df.loc[i, 'extended_off'] = 0
    elif ((df.loc[i-2, 'days_off'] == 0) and (df.loc[i+1, 'days_off'] == 0)): # normal weekend (no  following)
        df.loc[i, 'extended_off'] = 0
    elif df.loc[i, 'days_off'] == 0: # normal working day
        df.loc[i, 'extended_off'] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'extended_off'] = 1 # 3 or more days_off in a row
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be useful

```
df["new"] = df['days_off'].ne(df['days_off'].shift()).cumsum()
df["counts"] = df.groupby("new")['new'].transform('size')
((df.counts.ge(3)) & (df.days_off == 1)).astype(int)
```

Comment: Works as intended, a bit hard to follow if you are not profficient at pandas. It took me a while to dissect. If you want to go through it might help other people!

Comment: You're right it's a bit complex solution. I have just encountered such problems by now. I combined previous answers of questions I saw.